# Strange behavior in function parsing a date

Tags: r

I have a function that takes in a date and converts it to an offset in a matrix.  There is one row in the matrix per 15 minute time period.  I'm sure you could write this more elegantly or efficiently, but this appears to work, at least most of the time.  My problem is when I pass in an array of 16 or more dates to be converted; the results are way off.  Array of 15 appears fine.  Things I tried to make it work: treat the offset as a double (nope), comment out some of the function lines (sometimes it works, sometimes not), print the value out within the function (nope).  Clearly there is something going on here, but I'm out of things to try.  Is it something to do with lubridate?  I've used it similarly before with no problem.  Code is below, hopefully you can reproduce this; even if not please suggest something!

```
library(lubridate)

test15 <- structure(c(1407992400, 1407994200, 1407995100, 1407996000, 
1407996900, 1407998700, 1407999600, 1408001400, 1408002300, 1408004100, 
1408005000, 1408006800, 1408011300, 1408012200, 1408013100), 
class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Etc/GMT+5")
test16 <- structure(c(1407992400, 1407994200, 1407995100, 1407996000, 
1407996900, 1407998700, 1407999600, 1408001400, 1408002300, 1408004100, 
1408005000, 1408006800, 1408011300, 1408012200, 1408013100, 1407987000), 
class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Etc/GMT+5")
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# function to translate timestamp into time step offset
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
study.start <- as.Date("2014-08-13")
interval <- 15

getoffset <- function(bin.in)
    { #get offset function
    date.offset <-     as.numeric(difftime(as.Date(as.POSIXlt(bin.in)),study.start))
    hour.offset <- hour(bin.in)*(60/interval)
    min.offset <- minute(bin.in)/interval
    step.offset <- date.offset*24*(60/interval) + hour.offset + min.offset
    return(step.offset)
    } #get offset function

getoffset(test15)
getoffset(test16)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue here is that you need to specify the `unit` when using `difftime`.

```
getoffset <- function(bin.in,study.start,interval)
{ #get offset function
date.offset <-     as.numeric(difftime(as.Date(as.POSIXlt(bin.in)),study.start,units = "days"))
hour.offset <- hour(bin.in)*(60/interval)
min.offset <- minute(bin.in)/interval
step.offset <- date.offset*24*(60/interval) + hour.offset + min.offset
return(step.offset)
}
getoffset(test16,study.start=as.Date(as.POSIXlt("2014-08-13 00:00:00 GMT+5")),15)
[1]  96  98  99 100 101 103 104 106 107 109 110 112 117 118 119  90
```

Comment: That does it, thanks so much!  I wonder why it works some of the time.  I have some other similar code that never gave me any trouble.

Comment: @J.Krauel, it doesn't work on test16 before is because the last element in the test16 is on the date of 13th and without proper time value.  Hence when `difftime` guess the unit (under `units = "auto"`), a `secs` may have been used. And this is probably why you've seen large numbers.